# yum install php-tidy - no more mirrors

Tags: php, yum

Hi im trying to get the tidy extensions installed on centos running php 5.3

Thanks

```
Downloading Packages:
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-tidy-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-pdo-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-mysql-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-gd-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-xml-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-common-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-devel-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-cli-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.


Error Downloading Packages:
  php-tidy-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-tidy-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-cli-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-cli-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-pdo-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-pdo-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-devel-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-devel-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-mysql-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-mysql-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-common-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-common-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-xml-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-xml-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php-gd-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64: failure: php-gd-5.3.5-1.w5.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Comment: I believe this belongs in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo had a [recent problem](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) (13th Feb) and needed rebuilding - try the following and then try again:

```
yum clean all
```

[enter link description here](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/)

Comment: Came to say this worked for me when getting the error on centOS5.4 trying to install gcc